# Submit PHP form run function from included file

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Sorry for the basic question. I have looked at other answers here on Stackoverflow but here goes:

I have a simple form which should post the data to my mysql DB:

```
<form id="theatre" method="post" action="{$HTTP_HOST}admin/addTheatre.php"     autocomplete="on">
    <input type="hidden" name="id">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Please fill in the relevent fields.</label>
        <section>
            <label for="year">Year</label>
            <div>                   
                <select name="year" id="year">
                    <optgroup label="Year">
                            <option>2013</option>
                            <option>2012</option>
                            <option>2011</option>
                            <option>2010</option>
                            <option>2009</option>
                            <option>2008</option>
                            <option>2007</option>
                            <option>2006</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section><label for="part">Part</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="part" name="part" title="A Tooltip">
            </div>
        </section>
        <section><label for="name">Name</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" title="A Tooltip">
            </div>
        </section>
        <section><label for="theatre">Theatre</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="theatre" name="theatre" title="A Tooltip">
            </div>
        </section>
        <section><label for="director">Director</label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="director" name="director" title="A Tooltip">
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div>
                <button name="submit" class="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and in the addTheatre.php file i have:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    hcDB::getInstance()->insert_theatre($_POST['year'], $_POST['part'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['theatre'], $_POST['director']);
}
```

Which i should run the following function:

```
function insert_theatre($year, $part, $name, $theatre, $director) {
    $year = $this->real_escape_string($year);
    $part = $this->real_escape_string($part);
    $name = $this->real_escape_string($name);
    $theatre = $this->real_escape_string($theatre);
    $director = $this->real_escape_string($director);
    $this->query("INSERT INTO theatre (`year`, `part`, `name`, `theatre`, `director`)" .
            " VALUES (" . $year . "' , '" . $part . "' , '" . $name . "' , '" . $theatre . "' , '" . $director . "')");
    }
```

As far as i can tell, nothing is being submitted. As you can probably tell, i'm new to this, so apologies for the incompetence!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: do `print_r($_POST);` (or `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); die;`) and see what you received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, nothing being submitted, then probably your button doesn't have value and you trying to do

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//other stuff
}
```

it's ultimately false.

So try to change your button

```
<button name="submit" class="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

To

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of `query` and call [`errorInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) to see if you get any meaningful messages.

It should probably tell you the SQL is malformed:

```
$this->query("INSERT INTO theatre (`year`, `part`, `name`, `theatre`, `director`)" .
        " VALUES (" . $year . "' , '" . $part . "' , '" . $name . "' , '" . $theatre . "' , '" . $director . "')");
}
```

AFAICT `VALUES ("` should be changed to `VALUES('"` (the extra single quote).

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in your query, and no error handling, so you never see the error message mysql would provide:

```
" VALUES ('" . $year . "' , '"
          ^--- missing quote
```